# How to set up a QGIS project with SQL Server which can be opened on another computer?

Tags: qgis, sql-server

I am using QGIS with SQL server 2008. 
I need to save project on one computer and then copy project to another 20 clients!

After I save project and try to open it on another computer I am getting error. 
[image: HANDLE BAD LAYERS]

How I can setup project that can be used on another computer?

Comment: i think it uses  odbc connection, so you need to have System odbc connection with same name in other computer

Comment: Question , how your QGIS + MS SQL is working . My 32bit worked ok for a while , then some strange problems and my 64 bit installation didn't work at all with 2008R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. You need to add the database connection to each computer. Unfortunately this is stored as a registry setting (see the MSSQL section in the image below).

But you can script the installation of registry settings, so if you roll our QGIS to many computers somehow, include the registry settings for the QGIS database connections. The way I have them set up it uses the ODBC connection, so you'll need to script up that too.

I have an example of a registry script for installing ODBC connections for SQL Server, which is here: https://gist.github.com/alexgleith/9358893#file-sqlservergisdatabase-reg.

[image: registry setting]

Comment: I would be interested in seeing this Alex, can you post it?

Hope you are well!

Comment: Hi Morgan, I added a link. Let me know if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Love your work, should come in handy!